# Updating package on Anaconda environment

Tags: python, django, anaconda, package, environment

Is there a way to update only the django package on the python 3 environment to version 2.0?

My base version of python is 2.7.14. Anaconda 4.4.4. I created a new environment for python 3.6.3.

I installed django 1.11.8 (as this is the latest version available for python 2.7) on both environments but I need django 2.0 on my python 3 environment.

When I try:

```
conda install django=2.0
```

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- django=2.0

Current channels:

- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch

... with a few more similar links

Am I missing something?
Is this even possible to do within an environment in the python 2 Anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
conda install django=2.0 -c conda-forge
```

That will use the [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) channel.